# What is the recommended approach for SlugField validation in Django REST framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm building a RESTful API using the Django REST framework.  One of my models looks a bit like this:

```
class Zone(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    ... other fields
```

So I have built a serializer like this:

```
class ZoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Zone
        fields = ('name', ... other fields)
```

When posting data to create a new zone, I'm not sure how much validation I am responsible for and how much should take place automatically.  I've tried the following test cases:

1. When `name` is a valid slug of 50 characters or less, validation succeeds.
2. When `name` is a valid slug of 50+ characters, validation fails with an appropriate error message.
3. When `name` is an invalid slug (e.g. "abc def"), validation succeeds and a Zone is created with the invalid name.

Digging into the code I can see that the **length** of a field is validated by `django.core.validators.MaxLengthValidator` in `run_validators` in `rest_framework/fields.py`, but `validate_slug` is not included in the list of validators.

I know that I can add a `validate_name` method to my serializer like this:

```
def validate_name(self, attrs, source):
    """
    Make sure this is a slug field
    """
    value = attrs[source]
    if not validators.validate_slug(value):
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Not a slug")
    return attrs
```

but this seems like overkill.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like there's a valid pull request in there. :) `validate_slug` probably should happen automatically.

Best course of action:

1. Double check the Django slug form field behavior against the REST framework serializer field behavior - are they definitely different?
2. Raise a ticket for the issue, noting what you've determined from (1).
3. Try to write a failing test case and submit it as a pull request.
4. Update the PR with the fix if possible.
5. Profit!!!11!!!!  (Well, get your name in the credits, and get a nice warm feeling for having contributed the fix)

Cheers,

Tom

Comment: Hi Tom - thanks for your response and thanks very much for DRF - it's great!  I was comparing the Django and REST Framework `fields` code as your answer came in - once I've got everything sorted I'll do as you suggest.

Comment: Link to the subsequently merged pull request, for any future readers: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/875

Comment: Thanks for the update ! Nevertheless, the slug_validate seems to be problematic for PUT request, since it retrieves an "Already exists" error when I want to update an object entering the same slug. Updating an object through the PrimaryKEy should not raise this error if they are the same, IMHO